# Disable Services to keep Microsoft Surface Pro 3 Cool

Tags: windows-10, process, services, cooling, microsoft-surface-pro-3

My Surface Pro 3 has suffered some sort of thermally related damage, basically if it gets much warmer than it is when idle it just shuts down. No warning or prompting just clicks off. Event viewer gives no reason. I assume that something on the main board expands when heated and causes the fault. "Tech support" was useless (surprise surprise) in solving the issue, but that's beside the point because I have another computer to use. However, for reasons, I need to use the damaged computer for some work and was wondering what if anything could be done with the OS to help keep the computer cool.

So far I have uninstalled all the nonessential programs and made sure what remained was not running background services. I have also taken steps to limit power usage and disabled Cortana and one drive. What else can I do?

If it helps, the work I am doing is writing with [TexStudio](http://www.texstudio.org/) and should be limited to that and only that. No internet or other programs should be needed.

Comment: Just RMA it, software won't make a big difference.

Comment: @Sam I agree, but this kinda came up and I'm just looking for any little bit to help out.

Comment: Disabling services is unlikely to resolve your issue as available CPU will still be used when there are loads. That said, BlackViper has the best and most researched lists of services that can be disabled: http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/

Comment: @music2myear Thanks, I'll give it a look see

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do it limit the processor to the lowest state you can.  You will first have to unlock the power options as by default you cannot change most of the power options on the Surface.

Open up the registry editor and go to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power
```

Double click `CsEnabled` and set it to `1`, then reboot your Surface.

After you have rebooted then you will be able to properly modify the power plans by going to Control Panel (the old one) and Power Options.  You can see if the "Power Saver" plan helps, or you can be even more restrictive and limit the CPU `Maximim processor state` to some low percentage:

[image]

For more information on unlocking the power plans and some good images of what you expect to see have a look at this [SurfaceTip](https://surfacetip.com/how-to-unlock-power-plans-on-surface-devices/) page.